# XAML - Converter within Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to include a Converter for TextBlock' Text property within a Style. I have the following code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="StringFormatStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <converters:StringFormatConverter />
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="some text" Style="{StaticResource StringFormatStyle}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}" Style="{StaticResource StringFormatStyle}" />
```

The problem is that the `Convert` method of my Converter isn't being called. The style is applied (100% sure of that).

What could be the problem of the converter not being applied to the TextBlock' Text property?

Long story short: I have several `double` properties in my ViewModel and I would like to display them formatted using a Converter.

PS: My `StringFormatConverter` looks like this:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. 
In style you set text to some invalid binding with only a converter. And later you set it to static text.

If you want to add specific handling to a value and want to avoid code duplicates, use attached variable.

Also note that you're creating two converters actually. One in style and one in resources. So just reference the one from resources, don't need to create it in style again.

Here's attached property sample.

```
public class TextConv: DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Text",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(TextConv),
      new PropertyMetadata(null, OnValueChanged)
    );
    public static void SetText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
    public static string GetText(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }
    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject obj,  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   {
       obj.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, args.NewValue.ToString() + "Hello!");
   }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<TextBlock local:TextConv.Text="some text" />
```

It might not work out of the box but you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Note: you have to replace the Boolean to string in public static void SetText(UIElement element, Boolean value); or it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Text` property explicitly, that will override the property setter in the style.

Use your converter in the `Binding` instead of the `Style`.

```
Text="{Binding AppName, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverterKey}}"
```

Comment: That way it works, but I want to extract the Converter into a Style. Suppose I have several TextBlocks, and I don't want to reapply the converter every time.

Comment: Than you should use attached variable to add converter. Note that you're setting "Text" twice. That's why converter is not applied

Comment: Maybe should I convert the string inside the ViewModel and create a property AppNameFormatted? Is it a better approach?

Comment: Well not really. With attached property approach you can convert any value including constant. But if you use it like Theodosious suggests than you will be able to convert only what is set in YourTextProperty. So it's less generic approach

Comment: The app I am creating is an Universal App (one ViewModel for Desktop and Phone). Would the attached property works in this case, for both apps?

Comment: Yes, of course. There might be small difference between WPF and WindowsRuntime XAML. But it's supported everywhere.